# java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, hikaricp

---

Hi everyone, have a spring batch application trying to run a batch job but getting the error:-

java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.

my hikari configuration:-

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=40
    spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
    spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=120000
    spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

my batch job config:-

```
 @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(25); // Set the number of threads to be used for parallel processing
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(25); // Set the maximum number of threads
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("privacyUpdateMigrationBatch-thread-");
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

@Bean
    public Step privacyUpdateMigrationJobStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("PrivacyUpdateMigrationJob")
                .<PrivateRegEmailAliasData, PrivateRegEmailAliasData>chunk(1000)
                .reader(privacyUpdateMigrationJobReader)
                .writer(privacyUpdateMigrationJobWriter)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(25)
                .build();
    }

@Bean(name = "dataSourceEdb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "batch.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceEdb() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").build();
    }
```

error:-

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:83) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:100) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:87) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:45) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:130) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:95) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:66) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:73) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:62) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) [spring-core-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:336) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:421) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:9.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:9.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
```

I have tried to decrease throttleLimit but its only working below then 9. also tried to increase the connectionTimeout but that also not works

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: It's a hard networking error. That app is not reaching the database host at that port so a "regular" troubleshooting applies: DNS resolution, ping, telnet to that db port (or netcat), etc.